# Проверка в xlsx соседних клеток при создании игры "Сапёр"

Tags: java, javafx, xlsx

Пишу сапёр, написал поле 8 на 8 и столкнулся с проблемой, много большого и нудного кода.
суть в том, что при запуске новой игры карта создаёт поло из ноликов 16 на 16, после создаёт бомбы, которые являются цифрой 9, и вычисляет значение для каждой ячейки (для центральных это проверка 8 ячеек), и всё это происходит в xlsx файле. Проблема в том, что когда я делал поле 8 на 8, столкнулся с тем, что нужно считать кол-во бомб покруг клетки приходилось вручную, но я понял одну зависимость. Что при счёте центральных клеток (там где 8 клетов вокруг нужно проверить) я могу проверить так: из строки и столбца я сделаю следующие вычесления, (слева то, что нужно сделать с строкой, справа - столбцем):

```
- -
- 0
- +
0 +
+ +
+ 0
+ -
0 -
```

написал код, но он не работает, как это можно сделать, ведь писать всё для каждой ячейки будет сложно(.
Вот код:

```
 public static void Get_Box_Value() throws IOException {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(link);
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        int r1 = 3, r2 = 14;
        int c1 = 3, c2 = 14;
        for(int i = r1; i <= r2; i++) {
            for (int j = c1; j <= c2; j++) {
                      //проверяю ячеку на наличие бомбы

                int iA8 = (int) workbook.getSheetAt(0).getRow(i).getCell(j).getNumericCellValue();
                if (iA8 != 9) {
                    int Value_cell = 0;
                    String link = "./map16_16.xlsx";
                    FileInputStream currDir = new FileInputStream(link);
                    Workbook workbook2 = new XSSFWorkbook(currDir);

                    //вычисляю значение каждой боковой ячейки от этой ячейки

                    int iA1 = (int) workbook2.getSheetAt(0).getRow(i--).getCell(j--).getNumericCellValue();
                    int iA2 = (int) workbook2.getSheetAt(0).getRow(i--).getCell(j).getNumericCellValue();
                    int iA3 = (int) workbook2.getSheetAt(0).getRow(i--).getCell(j++).getNumericCellValue();
                    int iA4 = (int) workbook2.getSheetAt(0).getRow(i).getCell(j++).getNumericCellValue();
                    int iA5 = (int) workbook2.getSheetAt(0).getRow(i++).getCell(j++).getNumericCellValue();
                    int iA6 = (int) workbook2.getSheetAt(0).getRow(i++).getCell(j).getNumericCellValue();
                    int iA7 = (int) workbook2.getSheetAt(0).getRow(i++).getCell(j--).getNumericCellValue();
                    int iA9 = (int) workbook2.getSheetAt(0).getRow(i).getCell(j--).getNumericCellValue();

                    //проверяю на наличие бомб

                    if (iA1 == 9) {
                        Value_cell++;
                    }
                    if (iA2 == 9) {
                        Value_cell++;
                    }
                    if (iA3 == 9) {
                        Value_cell++;
                    }
                    if (iA4 == 9) {
                        Value_cell++;
                    }
                    if (iA5 == 9) {
                        Value_cell++;
                    }
                    if (iA6 == 9) {
                        Value_cell++;
                    }
                    if (iA7 == 9) {
                        Value_cell++;
                    }
                    if (iA9 == 9) {
                        Value_cell++;
                    }
                    Row A3R = sheet.getRow(i);
                    A3R.getCell(j).setCellValue(Value_cell);
                }

            }
        }

        //сохраняю

        file.close();

        FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(new File(String.valueOf(link)));
        workbook.write(outFile);
        outFile.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это вполне ужасно)) Для начала попробуйте хотя бы соблюдать правила именования переменных/методов/классов, использовать осмысленное название переменных и не программировать путем исключения. В этом коде ничего нельзя понять и гарантировать, что он будет работать после исправлений тоже довольно сложно. Но править уже будете сами.  Как избавляться от подобного "дублирующего" кода , думаю, поймете:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class Main {

    private final static int FROM_CELL = 3, TO_CELL = 14;

    public static void getBoxValue(String inputFile, String outputFile) throws IOException {
        try (InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile); 
                OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(outputFile)); 
                XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream)) {
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            for (int i = FROM_CELL; i <= TO_CELL; i++) {
                for (int j = FROM_CELL; j <= TO_CELL; j++) {
                    if (getValue(workbook, i, j, 9)) {
                        int cellValue = searchValue(workbook, i, j, 9);                        
                        sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j).setCellValue(cellValue);
                    }                    
                }
            }   
            workbook.write(outputStream);
        }
        
    }

    private static int searchValue(Workbook workbook, int i, int j, int targetValue) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int k = i - 1; k <= i + 1; k++) {
            for (int l = j - 1; l <= j + 1; l++) {
                if (i == k && l == j) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (getValue(workbook, k, l, targetValue)) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    private static boolean getValue(Workbook workbook, int i, int j, int targetValue) {
        return Double.valueOf(workbook.getSheetAt(0).getRow(i).getCell(j).getNumericCellValue()).intValue() == targetValue;
    }

}
```

Comment: Здравствуйте. Да согласен, что код ужасен и названия переменных и методов в приведённом коде не соответствуют "нормам", но я только учусь. Так вот, всё работает! Спасибо большое, думал на такой вопрос могут и не ответить. Удачи!

Comment: только я до конца не понял логику, можно попросить вас написать под для боковых строк/столбцов, по логике я должен просто везде убрать j или i и заменить его на ноль (в зависимости от стороны), но так не получается. Буду благодарен)

Comment: @World 006 не совсем понял, что именно нужно написать? вы о логике метода searchValue говорите? он ищет определенное  значение (в данном случае 9) вокруг вашей клетки. для этого используется 2 вложенных цикла. вроде все просто....

Comment: всё, получилось.